# Keycloak not using custom authentication flow

Tags: authentication, keycloak

Im struggling with auto linking my accounts. I have different IDP's where i can ensure that the identity of the user is the person it is. User registration therefor is also not allowed. On default Keycloak prompts with a link user flow which works fine.

However for my endusers this is confusing so i would like the option to automaticly link the IDP to the user account.

For this i created a second authentication flow called "auto link". However when i assign it to the identity provider it is still using the "first-broker-login" flow. (see screenshots).

See below some extract info:

The actual flow itself:
[image]

Linking the flow to the IDP:
[image]

Login result:
[image]